# Check if a log file already exists in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rspec

I am looking to do the following:

```
new_logger = Logger.new('log/exceptions.log')
new_logger.level = Logger::ERROR
new_logger.error('THIS IS A NEW EXCEPTION!')

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = new_logger
```

But I only want that log file created if it doesn't already exist. Would I literally just use the `File.exist?`

How would you test this? (using rspec) and if the log file gets to big does rails (or is the web server) compress the file and create a new one, like: `log.zip, log_2`

Comment: ...otherwise you want to append new log entries to existing contents, correct?

Comment: yes, if it exists, append, else create. My concern with File.exist? is that it doesnt know about the way a rails project is set up so im not sure how I would get all the info in there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, actually, en example [in `Logger` docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html):

```
file = File.open('foo.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND)
# To create new (and to remove old) logfile, add File::CREAT like:
# file = File.open('foo.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
logger = Logger.new(file)
```

If a file to be written does not exist, it is created automatically on an attempt to open it.

Comment: Here I thought Logger was apart of rails for some reason >.>

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised to find it in the core too. `pry` makes searching for given objects in the docs surprisingly easy: `show-doc Logger`, done.